# Find the equation in polar coordinates of the line through the point (−2,−3) and with slope 1/7

Tags: polar-coordinates, parametric

I'm having some trouble with my assignment problem. I have no idea where to start at the moment and would appreciate any tips to help me get started on solving this problem.

## Question

I'm asked to find the equation in **polar coordinates** of the line through the point **(-2,-3)** and with slope **1/7**

Comment: You should edit your question to show what work you have done on the problem. For example, you have enough information to find the equation of the line in Cartesian coordinates. What did you get for that equation? (in $Ax+By=C$ form.)

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I wasn't sure of where to even start so I had nothing unfortunately.

Comment: When translating from Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates you first have to have the Cartesian equation (the equation in terms of $x$ and $y$) then replace $x=r\cos(\theta),\,y=r\sin(\theta)$ and solve the resulting equation (which will then be in terms of $r$ and $\theta$) for $r$. Sometimes it may be a challenge to solve for $r$ but not in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: First, find the equation of the line in Cartesian ($y=mx+b$ (shouldn't be very difficult)). You know the slope is  $\frac{1}{7}=m$. They gave you another point that it goes through/satisfies. Use that to find $b$ and you'll have the equation of your line in Cartesian Coordinates. Then, use the relationship between Cartesian and Polar to get the polar equation (maybe $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ will ring a bell? (try to just drawing a triangle and review what Polar coordinates and Cartesian coordinates mean)) Good luck.

Comment: Oh geez! You just beat me to this and the fact that you are doing it the same way +1. :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I was able to solve it. Drawing the triangle really helped me grasp the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You can write the equation in cartesian coordinate as $y=mx+q$, than substitute
$y=\rho \sin \theta$ and $x=\rho \sin \theta$. From this it is easy to obtain  $\rho$ as a function of $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

we have the equation in cartesian coordinates as $$y=\frac{1}{7}x-\frac{19}{7}$$
now we have $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{x}{r}$$ and $$\sin(\theta)=\frac{y}{r}$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Your line has the following cartesian equation

$$y=\frac {1}{7}x+b $$

with $$b=-3+\frac {2}{7}=-\frac {19}{7} $$

thus

$$r=\sqrt {x^2+y^2}=f (x) $$

and $$\tan (\theta)=\frac {y}{x} =g (x)$$
or $$x=h (\theta) $$

thus, your polar equation will be
$$r=f (h (\theta)). $$